# Slack API error 403 on modal interactions even though it accepts slash commands

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

Background: I am using two features from slack API: slash commands and interactions. I have a service that handles both when Slack API redirects.

The problem is:

- **slash commands** are accepted and redirected by slack to my service with no issues:

  - I can see it in the log coming in
  - It is handled by the service (shows the modal which the user is about to interact with)
- **interactions** are rejected; Slack API simply gives back 403 to the end-user (shown in the same modal). I know the request is not redirected because my logs don't show it.

Again: slash commands just work with no problems, but interactions don't, even though they are configured with the same `Request URL`.

I searched for this problem in slack and tried looking in all the configurations in the slack API, but I couldn't find anything useful.
I have tried using a different Request URL (by appending `/interactions`) but with no avail; slack API still blocks it from my service.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I’m having the same issue but with slash commands. All requests are simply rejected with 403 and never reach my app.

Comment: It was some problem in our proxy servers; still don't know what it was.